# Transition from one animation to another

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

So, simple question:

I have an element, which has a animation in its normal state - a transform-animation (`perspective`, `rotateX` and `rotateZ` - but just `rotateZ` changes) which runs constantly. On `:hover` I want to change that animation (remove the `rotateX` and `perspective` transform, but keep the `rotateZ` animation) - that's no problem, but I want the animation transition into the new animation and I have no clue how to accomplish that.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2bz4y450/)

from:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotatespace {
  0% {
    transform:perspective(555px) rotateX(55deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform:perspective(555px) rotateX(55deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg) scale(1.25);
  }
}
```

to:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes rotateflat {
  0% {
    transform:perspective(0) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform:perspective(0) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(360deg) scale(1.25);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying all the transform styles to one element you could use the `:before` pseudo element for the animated block and the element itself for the "3D" effect (the `rotateX`).

Example:

```css
.block {
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    transform-origin: center center 0px;
    overflow:visible;
    transform:perspective(555px) rotateX(55deg) scale(1.25);
    transition:transform .5s;
}
.block:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    animation-name: rotatespace;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.block:hover {
    transform:perspective(555px) rotateX(0deg) scale(1.25);    
}
@keyframes rotatespace {
    0% {
        transform:rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I think the perspective change (555px to 0px) mentioned in question need not happen on hover because there is only a 0 degree rotate. Not that you are changing it in your answer but just an observation.

Comment: Thanks Harry. Your comment makes sense. Since setting the `perspective` to `0` made my Firefox not display the animation anymore I decided to keep the `perspective` at `555px` assuming jacksbox will understand where we're going and be able to apply what he wants himself.

Comment: oh, that is a nice solution - in my case, I have to wrap my element into another instead of the before, but the basic concept stays the same. 
I´ll wait till I accept that as the answer, because I want too see, if there is another solution without wrapping/:before. But a lot of thanks at this point!

Comment: Nice answer. I would be very surprised if there is a solution that doesn't involve nested elements of some kind